# Simple Javascript If Statement Issue

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var sentence = prompt('Enter Sentence Here: ')
if(sentence === 'Billy'){
console.log('Great!');
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to return "Great!' if the sentence isn't just "Billy" For Example how could you return "Great!" if the sentence was "My name is Billy" so what what I'm asking for is how to I get the if statement to scan the sentence and determine if that word is present then return what I wish.

My apologies for the simplicity and stupidity, this is my first day learning JS.

Comment: `if( sentence.indexOf("Billy") > -1)` would be one way.

Comment: Naive approach: `array = string.split(); for(i of array) if(i=='Billy') console.log('Great');`

Comment: i mean console.log "Great!"

Answer (score 4):

You should use regular expressions, searching for Billy:

```
/billy/i.test("I am Billy")
```

Comment: Using regular expressions to search for a fixed string? Really?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i dont see why not? using test looks much neater than some other solution, plus its one of the fastest solutions.

Comment: This is the fastest solution because of how optimised regex matching is.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh would you mind to give me a little explanation why is using regexp test method better than the match I did use? Always had that curiosity ^^

Comment: Just benchmarked it, and as expected a literal string lookup is about 20% faster using `indexOf` than a static regex. Throw case-insensitivity into the mix, however, and regex barely breaks a sweat while `toLowerCase().indexOf()` suffers halved performance.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting tidbit of info.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Nice. But I'd still stick to `indexOf`. It's easier to parameterize as in `s.indexOf(x)` where `x` is an argument. But that's just my opinion, I get the power of precompiled/cached RegEx-es :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `indexOf` as follows:

```
if (sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf("billy") !== -1) {
```

All lower case is an additional laxing of the condition.

This is your full code:

```js
var sentence;

sentence = prompt("Enter Sentence Here: ");

if (sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf("billy") !== -1)
{
  console.log("Great!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.includes` or `.indexOf` which scan a string for a substring.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

includes takes a string to search for and returns true if it finds it, otherwise false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

indexOf takes a string to search for and if it finds it, will return the starting index of that string, so `'hello'.indexOf('ello') => 1` If it doesn't find it, it returns -1;

.includes

```
var sentence = prompt('Enter Sentence Here: ');

if (sentence.includes('Billy')) {
  console.log('Great!');
}
```

.indexOf

```
var sentence = prompt('Enter Sentence Here: ');

if (sentence.indexOf('Billy') > -1) {   
  console.log('Great!'); 
}
```

Something to note is that it is case sensitive, so make sure you are typing 'Billy'. You can make use of `toLowerCase` and search for `billy` as well, and that way it would be case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `indexOf`

```
var sentence = prompt('Enter Sentence Here: ');//"My name is Billy"

if(sentence.indexOf("Billy") !== -1){
     console.log('Great!');
}
```

Incase you want case insensitive , you can use toLower() on string and then search for "billy"

```
  if(sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf("billy") !== -1){
       console.log('Great!');
  }
```

Using regex is also one of the good options.

```
if(/billy/i.test(sentence)){ 
     console.log('Great!');
 }
```

Thanks for reading,

Answer (score 1):

## Regular expression

```
/billy/i.test("I am Billy");
```

## es6 includes

```
"I am Billy".toLowerCase().includes("billy");
```

## es6 contains

```
"I am Billy".toLowerCase().contains("billy");
```

## old indexOf

```
"I am Billy".toLowerCase().indexOf("billy") !== -1;
```

Comment: @Coldspeed thanks, you should mention this in the edit comment, not here

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
if(prompt('Enter Sentence Here: ').toLowerCase().indexOf("billy") >= 0)
{
    console.log('Great!');
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use includes like:

```
if( sentence.includes('Billy') )
```

Check [Browser support](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)